# Easily make a copy of my android application

Tags: android, version-control

I have an android application for one client, and he wants to make a 99% similar app for different country.

Almost everything is the same, only a few bitmaps would need to be replaced, address of API server will change, language file will change, but the code should stay the same, **BUT** I will need a different package name.

What is a simple way to make a clone of the app that will allow me to make code changes to one version, merge them with the new version (or versions), but keep the package name?

Or should I have everything in one project folder and then write and run some script that will change package names and swap content files? My iOS friend will probably need a few different #defines, but what should I do here, so I can maintain both versions in the future?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

declare your original project as library, then create 2 new projects each for one language and let them include original project as library

then you can go ahead and just override bitmaps and constants you need.

this way, if you need any changes in core functionality, you just change your library project, and changes will propagate to both of extending projects

read more about library projects here:

https://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html#LibraryProjects

Comment: But I have about 30 activities in the old project, will I need to create all of the activities in both of the new projects? Or my AndroidManifest.xml can point to activities in the library?

Comment: you can point to the library, but you will need to provide full package path for them

e.g. com.mypackage.mylibrary.MyActivity